# Do I need csrf tokens after login?

Tags: ajax, node.js, security, reactjs, csrf

I'm building a simple todo list where the user will login (with csrf-token) and then be able to add items to the todo list. Would I need to add csrf_tokens to submissions using AJAX (todo list items) after the the user has already logged in? I'm using session based authentication.

Comment: I don't get why people downvote you, seems legit to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'd say yes you have to do it, look at this excerpt taken from [owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Client.2FUser_Prevention) ( Open Web Application Security Project ) documentation:

> When targeting a normal user, a successful CSRF attack can compromise
>   end-user data and their associated functions. If the targeted end user
>   is an administrator account, a CSRF attack can compromise the entire
>   Web application. The sites that are more likely to be attacked are
>   community Websites (social networking, email) or sites that have high
>   dollar value accounts associated with them (banks, stock brokerages,
>   bill pay services). **This attack can happen even if the user is logged**
>   **into a Web site using strong encryption (HTTPS)**. Utilizing social
>   engineering, an attacker will embed malicious HTML or JavaScript code
>   into an email or Website to request a specific 'task url'. The task
>   then executes with or without the user's knowledge, either directly or
>   by utilizing a Cross-site Scripting flaw (ex: Samy MySpace Worm).